# Any way to create a permissions-like sea of checkboxes?

Tags: forms

Basically I am looking for something like this (square brackets are checkboxes):

```
  A  B  C  D  E
1 [] [] [] [] []
2 [] [] [] [] []
3 [] [] [] [] []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way is to create a FAPI checkboxes array then theme it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Node Permission Grid](http://drupal.org/project/node_permissions_grid) module ?

This will give permission grid like [image]

Comment: Not exactly. I am trying to do this in a custom module. Permissions have nothing to do with it, other than being a well-known example of what I wanted.

Comment: Ok.i just got it wrong..any way we can do it using custom module..